# Windows Server 2008 R2 - Limit number of sessions created by a PARTICULAR user

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, rdp, user-accounts, user-permissions

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server which can be connected by my guest user through RDP to access a custom desktop application.

I want to limit each user to be able to access the custom desktop application by maximum of 3 PC.

Example:

- I have 2 guest users `A` and `B` now I want that maximum of 3 PC can connect to server with user credential of `A`
- If more try to login then should not allow them and give them a message `"Maximum Users Are Already Connected"`.

Comment: What service do you want them to access? you don't mention one

Comment: @Chopper3 please see the question again i have updated it. I want to limit number of sessions created by a user that accesses my software on the server.